# W3 Total Cache permissions

Tags: wordpress, w3-total-cache

**Problem description**

When I try open W3 Total Cache settings page I got the following error:

> You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page

This is the only one plugin that I cannot edit. It's installed on multisite page and it's activated for the whole network. I can normally delete it and activate / deactivate for the whole network. The error occurs when I'm trying to open settings page on one of the pages within this network.

I'm using `localhost` - just so you know but I'm quite sure that it does not change anything in this case.

**Solving attempts**

I have checked *user capabilities* and *user_level* in database (they are set to administrator and "10").

I tried reloading `APC` and `PHP-FPM` (found this while googling). I have tried clearing browser cache and opening site in incognito mode.

I have tried reinstalling plugin, deactivate it and activate again (multiple times).

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your permissions of the wp-contents and all folders within it. 
Try 774, if that doesn't work try 775.
This should fix your issue, let me know if you have any issues.